# How to put a default date in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I want my `datetimepicker` to have a default value which is the current date. How can I achieve this? I already read the documentation but can't find anything to achieve that. Can someone help me? I want the format of the default value is `MM dd, yyyy`.

[image]

Here's my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="dtp_input2">Date</label>
  <div class="input-group date form_date col-md-3" data-date="" data-date-format="MM dd, yyyy">
    <input id="dtp_input2" name="date" class="form-control" size="10" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn: 1,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0,
});
```

Comment: have you tried setting the value of the `input`?

Comment: `value="01 1, 2017"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the value after setting up the datetimepicker:

```
$('.form_date').datetimepicker({
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn: 1,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0,
});
$('#dtp_input2').val(Date());
```

Comment: Actually, this will not set the "Date" value for the datepicker, rather only "fill in" the textbox. Without the datepicker receiving the value, the point kind of seems moot

Comment: initially it works but if focus out the date sets to nothing !!!

Answer (score 12):

In my case : 
Insert this `defaultDate: new Date()` code into your javascript datetimepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        viewMode: 'years',
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
});
```

Comment: This is an accurate, much simpler and robust solution. This should be marked as the right answer!!

Comment: Really, this is a simple solution. What are all other options available for this datetimepicker with all the options? Any detailed reference link?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like from the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that you can set a `defaultDate` when instantiating the datetimepicker.

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
        disabledDates: [
            moment("12/25/2013"),
            new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
            "11/22/2013 00:53"
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not work for me, I am using it like this 
$('#expiryDateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
   minDate:moment().add(1,'h'),
                        defaultDate:moment().add(1,'M'),
   format: 'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a',
   showClose:true
  }). 
It is showing minDate as value

Comment: @Fayaz Does it work if you don't use minDate? I did read in the documentation that sometimes minDate will override defaultDate.

Answer (score 3):

This solution only uses the methods provided by the bootstrap datetimepicker.

You can declare your datetimepicker as you did and then do this:

```
$('#datepicker input').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$('#datepicker input').datepicker('update');
$('#datepicker input').val('');
```

This way the date you set in the `setDate()` will be selectionned and the input will remain empty.
If you don't want the input to be empty, just remove these lines:

```
$('#datepicker input').datepicker('update');
$('#datepicker input').val('');
```

And if you want to play with that solution: Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/50L6e51x/1/)

---

```js
$('#datepicker input').datepicker({
  weekStart: 1,
  todayBtn: 1,
  autoclose: 1,
  todayHighlight: 1,
  startView: 2,
  minView: 2,
  forceParse: 0,
});

$('#datepicker input').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$('#datepicker input').datepicker('update');
$('#datepicker input').val('');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set current Date to a text field with JS like :

```js
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("target").value = d.toDateString();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="target">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the following one. It works fine for me.

```
$('.className').datepicker('setDate', 'now');
```