# Datetimepicker set value from Db

Tags: javascript, php, html, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using eonasdan Datetimepicker in my project but I can't really set the value that I'm getting from my DB in the input field

here is my HTML code

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Conference start</label>
    <div class='col-sm-10'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' name="datestart" value="<?=$vars['tstart']?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my JS code

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm'
    });
});
```

from my MYSQL DB, I get the DATETIME  in the variable `$VAR` but in the input field I always have the `"2020-04-04 00:00"` when it's supposed to be `"2020-04-09 02:35"`

if I inspect element using google chrome tools in the input value I see the correct date but in the field, I get the wrong DATETIME

Comment: The documentation does not mention providing the default date via the field value attribute anywhere, I think you might have to provide it via the `defaultDate` option, https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a default date in bootstrap datetimepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41897021/how-to-put-a-default-date-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker)